# Передача переменной с js в php

Tags: javascript, php

Есть скрипт, который производит умножение двух чисел

```
$("#one").on('input', recalcSum);
$("#two").on('input', recalcSum);

function recalcSum() {
  var res = $("#one").val() * $("#two").val() + '$';
  $("#res").text(res);
}
```

Нужно результат забить в переменную php и вывести на другой странице. Как это сделать?

Comment: Ajax и ему подобное...пользуйтесь поисковиком, так же тег form

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц а без Ajax никак?

Comment: @3 Darin с помощью `<form></form>`

Answer (score 1):

Если хочешь сделать на чистом php и js ну или с jQuery то самое простое это создай внутри формы тег, пропиши ему в ксс display: none; и далее с помощью js запиши в него значение далее есть такое событие - выбераешь форму в js $("form_id").submit(); и после этого в PHP пиши метод отправки который ты присвоил форме $res = $_Get/$_POST["name тега в который записано нужное значение"]

```
    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="res_form">
      <p id="res" style="display: none;" name"res"></p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var res = ....;
      $("#res").html = res;
      $("res_form").submit(); //если не работает напиши без jq document.querySelector("#res_form").submit();
</script>
<?php
  $res = $_POST["res"];
?>
```